# Unable to Run the Shellscript From Golang

Tags: go, sh

I have to run the installable shell script from the golang. I have to provide all yes option while running the script.

I can run it from command like,

```
yes | install.sh
```

How can i give the same in golang.

I tried the following,

```
c := exec.Command("/bin/bash", 'path to install.sh', '| yes');
err = c.Run()

c := exec.Command("/bin/bash", 'yes | ', 'path to install.sh')
err = c.Run()
```

But both are not working. I need a help for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Piping is a shell feature. If you need it - you need to run it as a bash/sh command.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with bash also but i cant give a piping command.

Comment: `"/bin/sh", "-c", "yes | path/to/install.sh"`

Comment: c := exec.Command("/bin/bash", 'yes | path to install.sh')

Comment: Thanks all of you for your responses. But unfortunately nothing solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with the below code and it works fine in my case.

```
cmd1 := exec.Command("/bin/bash","-c", "yes")
cmd2 := exec.Command("path to install.sh", "2>&1 >/dev/null")
cmd2.Stdin, _ = cmd1.StdoutPipe()
cmd2.Stdout = os.Stdout
_ = cmd2.Start()
_ = cmd1.Run()
_ = cmd2.Wait()
```